# Codesign OSX App Bundle with periods in MacOS directory names

Tags: macos, pyinstaller, codesign, app-bundle

I run this line:

```
codesign --verbose --force --deep --sign "Developer ID Application: Company" Company.app
```

and I get this error:

```
Company.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: /Users/me/repo/client/Company.app/Contents/MacOS/include/python2.7
```

I have narrowed the problem down to the fact that I have an app bundle that includes a few subdirectories in the Contents/MacOS directory that have periods in their names. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG201), codesign chokes on this because it believes any directory with a period in it is a bundle itself and rejects it (emphasis mine):

> Note that a location where code is expected to reside cannot generally contain directories full of nested code, because those directories tend to be interpreted as bundles. So this occasional practice is not recommended and not officially supported. If you do do this, do not use periods in the directory names. **The code signing machinery interprets directories with periods in their names as code bundles and will reject them** if they don't conform to the expected code bundle layout.

My bundle is being created by PyInstaller (tested version 3.1 and 3.2), and the directoriess are being pulled in automatically. Here are all the directories that have this problem:

```
Company.app/Contents/MacOS/include/python2.7
Company.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python2.7
Company.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python2.7/config
Company.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_menu.nib
Company.app/Contents/MacOS/tcl/http1.0
Company.app/Contents/MacOS/tcl/opt0.4
```

I looked [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing), and there was no mention of this issue, and I wanted to know if anyone has configuration ideas that might fix the problem without completely eliminating the dependencies from being included.

The bundle is created with the following command:

```
python $PYINSTALLER/pyinstaller.py \
-n $APP_NAME \
--paths $MODULE_SEARCH_PATH \
--windowed \
--icon $BUNDLEFILES_DIR/$APP_NAME.icns \
--distpath $BUNDLE_DIR/dist \
--osx-bundle-identifier com.company.$APP_NAME \
--exclude-module core.InternalTool \
main.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and after a *lot* of failures, I finally can get the `codesign` to work. I wrote a recipe for that with a script to automatically fix your app: [Recipe OSX Code Signing Qt](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing-Qt).

Comment: Sweet. I don't actually have that code to test this out, but at a glance it makes sense. So I'll mark this as accepted, but with the note that I haven't verified it.

Answer (score 1):

After writing this whole question, I noticed that our build script internally makes a copy of the app which followed the symlinks in the Contents/MacOS directory.

Just in case some other poor soul is looking for a similar answer, the solution is to have those directories live in the Contents/Resources dir, and symlink to them from the MacOS dir.